# What are some tech jobs for Math Majors?

Tags: careers, tech-industry, education

I’m currently getting my BS In Maths and trying to figure out what opportunities are out there after I’m done if I decide I don’t want to go to graduate school. My degree doesn’t really focus on programming although there are two classes that have to do with computer science, overall though, I’m curious what tech jobs would be the best for an undergrad math major, excluding Data Science type jobs. What programming languages are often used in these jobs?

Comment: What do you consider "tech", and where are you located?

Answer (score 2):

As far as tech jobs are concerned, you can apply for jobs as one of these positions: software developer, test engineer (Quality Assurance), technical recruiter, technical writer, application engineer, customer service engineer, sales engineer, etc...

---

**In particular, if you want to be a software developer, then here are some notes:**

> What programming languages are often used in these jobs?

If you are interested in software development, some of the popular computer languages  used in software development are (**in no particular order**): C#, Java, TypeScript, JavaScript, Python, C++, etc...

You can learn these languages from many online tutorial websites. In addition, you can also google to find out which computer languages are the most popular and in high demand.

---

Many companies are willing to hire Math majors to train them to be programmers, but candidates should spend time to search and find the right ones. A lot of industries need software developers such as financial tech firms, banks, game development, telecommunications, network security, manufactures, auto industry, media, entertainment, etc...

You can learn 1 or 2 programming languages, and use them to practice writing code to solve **Data Structures and Algorithms** coding problems. These companies will likely test your programming skills by giving you a live coding problem during the interview. Depending on the companies, there may be many rounds of technical interviews with live coding problems for a position.

It's also good to know the concepts of **Object Oriented Design** as this is one of the favorite topics in the interviews.